# ios uiviewcontroller child of uitabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, viewdidload

I have my project that have a uitabbarcontroller on the bottom.
a button of the tab bar links my viewcontroller...
the things works, I inserted some images, buttons and in the simulator I see these things.
now I need to make something on the load event...
I uncommented this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

but setting a breakpoint here, doesn't break..... the simulator loads the view correctly but doesn't load the viewDidLoad...

how can I solve this?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you still have this problem but I just ran into the exact same thing. In fact I had the problem a while ago and had to rack my brain to remember what I did. I solved it by making sure both the nib selection in the first tab and that class name selection in the last tab are set correctly. You can set just the nib file name and everything will appear to work but will instantiate a base class, likely a UIViewController. This is in IB where you set the attributes for each tab.